# Why this implementation of Foward DCT of Loffler's version doesn't work?

Tags: c++, opencv, dct

I'm trying to implement the Loeffler's version of 1D DCT but without any results... I followed the chain of operations shown in the flow diagram, but the image becomes white :( What I'm doing wrong?

The diagram:

[image: 1D DCT 8 BY LOEFFLER]

The code:

## include

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv/cv.hpp>
#include <pthread.h>
#include "highgui.h"
#include "cv.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

#define C3 851
#define S3 569

#define C1 1004
#define S1 200

#define C6 392
#define S6 946

#define R2 181

void dct2(Mat in, double dct[8][8], int xpos, int ypos) {
    int i;
    double rows[8][8];

    int x0, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8;

    //cout << S3 << " " << S1 << " " << S6 << endl;

    /* transform rows */
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {

        x0 = in.at<uchar>(xpos + 0, ypos + i);
        x1 = in.at<uchar>(xpos + 1, ypos + i);
        x2 = in.at<uchar>(xpos + 2, ypos + i);
        x3 = in.at<uchar>(xpos + 3, ypos + i);
        x4 = in.at<uchar>(xpos + 4, ypos + i);
        x5 = in.at<uchar>(xpos + 5, ypos + i);
        x6 = in.at<uchar>(xpos + 6, ypos + i);
        x7 = in.at<uchar>(xpos + 7, ypos + i);

        //STAGE 1
        int X0 = x0;

        x0 += x7;

        int X1 = x1;

        x1 += x6;

        int X2 = x2;

        x2 += x5;

        int X3 = x3;

        x3 += x4;
        x4 = X3 - x4;
        x5 = X2 - x5;
        x6 = X1 - x6;
        x7 = X0 - x7;

        //STAGE 2
        X0 = x0;
        X1 = x1;

        x0 += x3;
        x1 += x2;
        x2 = X1 - x2;
        x3 = X0 - x3;

        int X4 = x4;

        x4 = x4 * C3 + x7 * S3;
        x7 = x7 * C3 - X4 * S3;

        int X5 = x5;

        x5 = x5 * C1 + x6 * S1;
        x6 = x6 * C1 - X5 * S1;

        //STAGE 3
        X0 = x0;

        x0 += x1;
        x1 = X0 - x1;

        X2 = x2;

        x2 = R2 * (x2 * C6 + x3 * S6);
        x3 = R2 * (x3 * C6 - X2 * S6);

        X4 = x4;
        X5 = x5;

        x4 += x6;
        x5 = x7 - x5;
        x6 = X4 - x6;
        x7 += X5;

        //STAGE 4
        X4 = x4;

        rows[i][0] = x0;
        rows[i][4] = x1;
        rows[i][2] = x2 >> 17;
        rows[i][6] = x3 >> 17;

        rows[i][7] = (x4 + x7) >> 10;
        rows[i][3] = (x5 * R2) >> 17;
        rows[i][5] = (x6 * R2) >> 17;
        rows[i][2] = (x4 - x7) >> 10;

    }

    /* transform columns */
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {

        x0 = rows[0][i];
        x1 = rows[1][i];
        x2 = rows[2][i];
        x3 = rows[3][i];
        x4 = rows[4][i];
        x5 = rows[5][i];
        x6 = rows[6][i];
        x7 = rows[7][i];

        //STAGE 1
        int X0 = x0;

        x0 += x7;

        int X1 = x1;

        x1 += x6;

        int X2 = x2;

        x2 += x5;

        int X3 = x3;

        x3 += x4;
        x4 = X3 - x4;
        x5 = X2 - x5;
        x6 = X1 - x6;
        x7 = X0 - x7;

        //STAGE 2
        X0 = x0;
        X1 = x1;

        x0 += x3;
        x1 += x2;
        x2 = X1 - x2;
        x3 = X0 - x3;

        int X4 = x4;

        x4 = x4 * C3 + x7 * S3;
        x7 = x7 * C3 - X4 * S3;

        int X5 = x5;

        x5 = x5 * C1 + x6 * S1;
        x6 = x6 * C1 - X5 * S1;

        //STAGE 3
        X0 = x0;

        x0 += x1;
        x1 = X0 - x1;

        X2 = x2;

        x2 = R2 * (x2 * C6 + x3 * S6);
        x3 = R2 * (x3 * C6 - X2 * S6);

        X4 = x4;
        X5 = x5;

        x4 += x6;
        x5 = x7 - x5;
        x6 = X4 - x6;
        x7 += X5;

        //STAGE 4
        X4 = x4;

        dct[0][i] = x0;
        dct[4][i] = x1;
        dct[2][i] = x2 >> 17;
        dct[6][i] = x3 >> 17;

        dct[7][i] = (x4 + x7) >> 10;
        dct[3][i] = (x5 * R2) >> 17;
        dct[5][i] = (x6 * R2) >> 17;
        dct[1][i] = (x4 - x7) >> 10;

    }

}

#define COEFFS(Cu,Cv,u,v) { \
    if (u == 0) Cu = 1.0 / sqrt(2.0); else Cu = 1.0; \
    if (v == 0) Cv = 1.0 / sqrt(2.0); else Cv = 1.0; \
    }

void idct2(Mat in, double data[8][8], const int xpos, const int ypos) {
    int u, v, x, y;

    /* iDCT */
    for (y = 0; y < 8; y++)
        for (x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
            double z = 0.0;

            for (v = 0; v < 8; v++)
                for (u = 0; u < 8; u++) {
                    double S, q;
                    double Cu, Cv;

                    COEFFS(Cu, Cv, u, v);
                    S = data[v][u];

                    q = Cu * Cv * S
                            * cos(
                                    (double) (2 * x + 1) * (double) u * M_PI
                                            / 16.0)
                            * cos(
                                    (double) (2 * y + 1) * (double) v * M_PI
                                            / 16.0);

                    z += q;
                }

            z /= 4.0;
            if (z > 255.0)
                z = 255.0;
            if (z < 0)
                z = 0.0;

            in.at<uchar>(x + xpos, y + ypos) = (uchar) z;
        }
}

int main() {

    Mat in = imread("lena.bmp", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

    double DCT[8][8];

    for (int x = 0; x < 8; ++x) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 8; ++y) {

            dct2(in, DCT, x * 8, y * 8);
            idct2(in, DCT, x * 8, y * 8);

        }
    }

    imshow("original", in);

    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

The result of Lena's pic 64 x 64 pixels:

[image]

Comment: Looks like it's getting clamped, meaning most values are overflowing. Try it on a smaller image, maybe 4x4, that you can also calculate by hand so you can check your work. Use your debugger, or ask a more specific question. We're not doing your work for you.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv/cv.hpp>
#include <pthread.h>
#include "highgui.h"
#include "cv.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

/*
#define C1 cos(M_PI/16)
#define C3 cos(3*M_PI/16)
#define C5 cos(5*M_PI/16)
#define C6 cos(6*M_PI/16)
#define S6 sin(6*M_PI/16)
#define C7 cos(7*M_PI/16)

#define R2 sqrt(2.0)
*/

 #define C1 1004
 #define C3 851
 #define C5 569
 #define C6 392
 #define S6 946
 #define C7 200

 #define R2 181

void dct2(Mat in, double dct[8][8], int xpos, int ypos) {
    int i;
    double rows[8][8];

    int x0, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7;
    int tmp0, tmp1, tmp2, tmp3, tmp4, tmp5, tmp6, tmp7;

    int tmp10, tmp11, tmp12, tmp13;
    int z1, z2, z3, z4, z5;

    /* transform rows */
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {

        x0 = in.at<uchar>(xpos + 0, ypos + i);
        x1 = in.at<uchar>(xpos + 1, ypos + i);
        x2 = in.at<uchar>(xpos + 2, ypos + i);
        x3 = in.at<uchar>(xpos + 3, ypos + i);
        x4 = in.at<uchar>(xpos + 4, ypos + i);
        x5 = in.at<uchar>(xpos + 5, ypos + i);
        x6 = in.at<uchar>(xpos + 6, ypos + i);
        x7 = in.at<uchar>(xpos + 7, ypos + i);

        tmp0 = x0 + x7;
        tmp7 = x0 - x7;
        tmp1 = x1 + x6;
        tmp6 = x1 - x6;
        tmp2 = x2 + x5;
        tmp5 = x2 - x5;
        tmp3 = x3 + x4;
        tmp4 = x3 - x4;

        tmp10 = tmp0 + tmp3;
        tmp13 = tmp0 - tmp3;
        tmp11 = tmp1 + tmp2;
        tmp12 = tmp1 - tmp2;

        rows[i][0] = tmp10 + tmp11;
        rows[i][4] = tmp10 - tmp11;

        rows[i][2] = (R2 * (tmp12 * C6 + tmp13 * S6)) >> 17;
        rows[i][6] = (R2 * (tmp13 * C6 - tmp12 * S6)) >> 17;

        //ODD PART
        z1 = tmp4 + tmp7;
        z2 = tmp5 + tmp6;
        z3 = tmp4 + tmp6;
        z4 = tmp5 + tmp7;
        z5 = (z3 + z4) * R2 * C3;

        tmp4 = tmp4 * R2 * (-C1 + C3 + C5 - C7);
        tmp5 = tmp5 * R2 * (C1 + C3 - C5 + C7);
        tmp6 = tmp6 * R2 * (C1 + C3 + C5 - C7);
        tmp7 = tmp7 * R2 * (C1 + C3 - C5 - C7);

        z1 = z1 * R2 * (C7 - C3);
        z2 = z2 * R2 * (-C1 - C3);
        z3 = z3 * R2 * (-C3 - C5);
        z4 = z4 * R2 * (C5 - C3);

        z3 += z5;
        z4 += z5;

        rows[i][7] = (tmp4 + z1 + z3) >> 17;
        rows[i][5] = (tmp5 + z2 + z4) >> 17;
        rows[i][3] = (tmp6 + z2 + z3) >> 17;
        rows[i][1] = (tmp7 + z1 + z4) >> 17;

        //cout << trunc(rows[i][2]) << endl;

    }

    /* transform columns */
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {

        x0 = rows[0][i];
        x1 = rows[1][i];
        x2 = rows[2][i];
        x3 = rows[3][i];
        x4 = rows[4][i];
        x5 = rows[5][i];
        x6 = rows[6][i];
        x7 = rows[7][i];

        tmp0 = x0 + x7;
        tmp7 = x0 - x7;
        tmp1 = x1 + x6;
        tmp6 = x1 - x6;
        tmp2 = x2 + x5;
        tmp5 = x2 - x5;
        tmp3 = x3 + x4;
        tmp4 = x3 - x4;

        tmp10 = tmp0 + tmp3;
        tmp13 = tmp0 - tmp3;
        tmp11 = tmp1 + tmp2;
        tmp12 = tmp1 - tmp2;

        dct[0][i] = (tmp10 + tmp11) >> 3;
        dct[4][i] = (tmp10 - tmp11) >> 3;

        dct[2][i] = (R2 * (tmp12 * C6 + tmp13 * S6)) >> 20;
        dct[6][i] = (R2 * (tmp13 * C6 - tmp12 * S6)) >> 20;

        //cout << dct[0][i] << endl;

        //ODD PART
        z1 = tmp4 + tmp7;
        z2 = tmp5 + tmp6;
        z3 = tmp4 + tmp6;
        z4 = tmp5 + tmp7;
        z5 = (z3 + z4) * R2 * C3;

        tmp4 = tmp4 * R2 * (-C1 + C3 + C5 - C7);
        tmp5 = tmp5 * R2 * (C1 + C3 - C5 + C7);
        tmp6 = tmp6 * R2 * (C1 + C3 + C5 - C7);
        tmp7 = tmp7 * R2 * (C1 + C3 - C5 - C7);

        z1 = z1 * R2 * (C7 - C3);
        z2 = z2 * R2 * (-C1 - C3);
        z3 = z3 * R2 * (-C3 - C5);
        z4 = z4 * R2 * (C5 - C3);

        z3 += z5;
        z4 += z5;

        dct[7][i] = (tmp4 + z1 + z3) >> 20;
        dct[5][i] = (tmp5 + z2 + z4) >> 20;
        dct[3][i] = (tmp6 + z2 + z3) >> 20;
        dct[1][i] = (tmp7 + z1 + z4) >> 20;

        //cout << dct[0][i] << endl;

    }

}

#define COEFFS(Cu,Cv,u,v) { \
    if (u == 0) Cu = 1.0 / sqrt(2.0); else Cu = 1.0; \
    if (v == 0) Cv = 1.0 / sqrt(2.0); else Cv = 1.0; \
    }

void idct2(Mat in, double data[8][8], const int xpos, const int ypos) {
    int u, v, x, y;

    /* iDCT */
    for (y = 0; y < 8; y++)
        for (x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
            double z = 0.0;

            for (v = 0; v < 8; v++)
                for (u = 0; u < 8; u++) {
                    double S, q;
                    double Cu, Cv;

                    COEFFS(Cu, Cv, u, v);
                    S = data[v][u];

                    q = Cu * Cv * S
                            * cos(
                                    (double) (2 * x + 1) * (double) u * M_PI
                                            / 16.0)
                            * cos(
                                    (double) (2 * y + 1) * (double) v * M_PI
                                            / 16.0);

                    z += q;
                }

            z /= 4.0;
            if (z > 255.0)
                z = 255.0;
            if (z < 0)
                z = 0.0;

            in.at<uchar>(x + xpos, y + ypos) = (uchar) z;
        }
}

int main() {

    Mat in = imread("lena.bmp", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

    double DCT[8][8];

    for (int x = 0; x < in.cols/8; ++x) {
        for (int y = 0; y < in.rows/8; ++y) {
            dct2(in, DCT, x * 8, y * 8);
            idct2(in, DCT, x * 8, y * 8);
        }
    }

    imshow("original", in);

    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The problem was that I need shift right the final result by 3 (/8) :)